# VUE: Disable buttons until animation ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

how to prevent click when animation is in progress with **VUE**?

```
<button v-model="show" @click="show === 'showFirst'">click me first</button>
<button v-model="show" @click="show === 'showSecond'">click me second</button>

<transition :enter-active-class="'animated fadeIn'" :leave-active-class="'animated fadeOut'">
    <div class="first" key="1" v-if="showFirst">First Div</div>
    <div class="second" key="2" v-if="showSecond">Second Div</div>
</transition>
```

**VUE**

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return: {
           show: "showFirst"
        }
    }
}
```

After clicking on the first button, both will be deactivated until the animation ends. Is it possible either in this way or in another way?

Now when I click both buttons alternately, the animations interrupt each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<transition></transition>` JS hooks.(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks)

```
<transition @before-enter="disabled=true" @after-leave="disabled=false">
    <div class="first" key="1" v-if="showFirst">First Div</div>
    <div class="second" key="2" v-if="showSecond">Second Div</div>
</transition>
```

Comment: After edit this works for me: @leave="disabled=true" @after-enter="disabled=false". Thanks for tip! :) I will remember it next time.

Answer (score 1):

listen to transition end with vanilla js

```
const transition = document.querySelector('.transition');

transition.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
  console.log('Transition ended');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things I don't really get in your code though. Like why the buttons have v-models. What are you trying to perform two-way data binding for? I think just having the buttons trigger events is enough. 
And why your click events are comparing and not assigning.
You could use the disabled prop for the buttons too, so they're disabled respective to a boolean you're manipulating.
So probably it should be something like this:

```
<button @click="isActivated" :disabled="!isEnabled">click me first</button>
<button @click="isActivated" :disabled="!isEnabled">click me second</button>

<transition :enter-active-class="'animated fadeIn'" :leave-active-class="'animated fadeOut'">
    <div class="first" key="1" v-if="show === 'showFirst'">First Div</div>
    <div class="second" key="2" v-if="show === 'showSecond'">Second Div</div>
</transition>
```

Then depending on the timing of your animations, you can have a disabled function that you pass as a prop to the button element. 
Like this

```
data() {
 return {
  show: 'showFirst',
  isEnabled: true,
 }
},
methods: {
  isActivated(){
    //first starts off as false
     this.show === 'showFirst' ? this.show = 'showSecond' : this.show = 'showFirst'
     this.disableButtons();
  },
  disableButtons(){
    //disable the button then enable after the number of seconds of the animation
    this.isEnabled = false
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isEnabled = true
    }, noOfSecondsOfAnimation)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but even after setting the time it didn't work. It's probably arguing somewhere with my code. But thanks for the explanation, I'll remember it next time.